# Change beamer bibliography format

Tags: beamer, bibtex

In my beamer presentation item in bibliography looks like this:

[image]

How i can remove this strange change line breaks?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx,ragged2e,etoolbox,enumerate}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}

\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\stdsection}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Zim:07} \cite{Dal:88}

    \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
    \bibliographystyle{ugost2008}
    \bibliography{bl}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

bl.bib:

```
@Book{Zim:07,
  author   = {P. Zimbardo},
  title    = {Lucifer Effect Understanding How Good People Turn Evil [Текст]},
  year     = {2007},
  language = {russian},
}
```

[MWE on the sharelatex.](https://www.sharelatex.com/read/vthpwcmjzbzq)

Comment: To clarify your question: Are you asking about the inhomogeneous indention of lines or the the dash following the title?

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality. Up to date versions also automatically load `etoolbox`.

Comment: @samcarter, i mean year and title can be fitted in two lines instead of three, so i'm about line break after dash, there is no need in it and it looks bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `beamer` issues a `\par` in the `bibliography entry title` and `bibliography entry location` templates. You can redefine them:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption,ragged2e,enumerate}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    \cite{Zim:07}
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
    \bibliographystyle{ugost2008}
    \bibliography{bl}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted, but how can i edit the text color in bibliography? I added description in first poste.

Comment: @AlexanderZolkin Changing the colour is a different question.